# File upload does not move into folder while update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

here's the code:

```
<?php 

   if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
      extract($_POST);
      $filename = $_FILES['uni_image']['name'];
      $path = "uni_banner/";
      $move=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uni_image']['tmp_name'],$path.$_FILES['uni_image']['name']);
      $filename2 = $_FILES['logo']['name'];
      $path2 = "uni_logo/";
      $move=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo'['tmp_name'],$path2.$_FILES['logo']['name']);

      $sql = "update all_university set university_name='$university_name',uni_type='$uni_type',short_name='$short_name',courses='$courses',address='$address',city='$city',phone='$phone',website='$website',facilities='$facilities',courses_fee='$fee',about_us='$about_us',field='$field',priority='$priority',short_name='$short_name',state='$state',form_fee='$form_fee',university_commission='$university_commission',client_commission='$client_commission',form_type='$form_type',logo='$filename2',uni_image='$filename' where university_id='".$university_id."'"; 
      $corr=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
      if ( $corr === true)
        {
          echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert(' Record Update successfully');</script>"; 
        }
      else
        {
           echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Error');</script>";
        }
   }
?>

<input type="file" name="logo" id="logo">
<input type="file" name="uni_image" id="uni_image">
<input type="submit" name="update" id="update">
```

how can I move file into a folder while update file where $university_id will get it from url?

thank you

Comment: Any error in code?

Comment: Where do you get all the other data (like address, uni_type etc) you're using in your update query?

Comment: You should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries.

Answer (score 0):

try use all inputs inside form with valid action and method

```
<form action="file_path_of_upload_script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="logo" id="logo">
<input type="file" name="uni_image" id="uni_image">
<input type="submit" name="update" id="update">
</form>
```

// 
and also check folder permissions and valid folder path during uploading..

Answer (score 0):

*try to change this*

```
$move=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo'['tmp_name'],$path2.$_FILES['logo']['name']);
```

**with**

```
$move=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'],$path2.$_FILES['logo']['name']);
```

and your html part should be like

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="logo" id="logo">
<input type="file" name="uni_image" id="uni_image">
<input type="submit" name="update" id="update">
</form>
```